# A peice of code in my python script errors out everytime it runs

Tags: python-3.x

```
YN = input("Create An Account Y/N:")
Y = "Yy"
login = "login"


if YN in Y:
    print ("Creating Account!")
    user = input("Enter A Username:")
    passwd = input("Enter a Password:")
    passwd2 = input("Verify Password:")
else:
    log = input("Would you like to login? If so type login.To close this application type q:")

if login in log:
    u = input("What is your username?")
    p = input("What is your password?")
else:
    print ("Ok Bye!")
    quit()


if passwd == passwd2:
    print ("Password Verified")
else:
    print ("Passwords Do not Match! One More Try")
    passwd = input("Enter a Password:")
    passwd2 = input("Verify Password:")

if passwd == passwd2:
    print ("Password Verified")
else:
    print ("You Failed! Restart Application and type better next time!")
    quit()

file2write=open("Usernames.text",'w')
file2write.write(user)
file2write.close()

file2write=open("Passwords.text",'w')
file2write.write(passwd)
file2write.close()

f = open("guru99.txt", "r")
if f.mode == 'r':
    password =f.read()

print (password)
```

My code is above.

```
if passwd == passwd2:
    print ("Password Verified")
```

The problematic code is above.

What happens is when it runs it runs all fine and dandy until that peice of code. It tells me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Path/To/My/Project/main.py", line 22, in <module>
    if passwd == passwd2:
NameError: name 'passwd' is not defined
```

It is really annoying because it worked last night but when i start adding some code at the bottom which reads the username and password files it fails. I do not understand it. Please Help.

Comment: When you tried last night, did you type `Y` at the first prompt, and when you tried today, did you type `N`? `passwd` and `passwd2` will only be defined if you type `Y` or `y` (or `Yy`, or nothing).

Comment: oh god i feel like a dumbass. How do i do it so it dosent error out when i type N

Comment: Well, what do you want the program to do if they don't choose a password?

Comment: Give the user a choice to either quit or choose a password or login

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `passwd` and `passwd2` are only defined when the user chooses y or Y at the beginning. You probably want to account for that. Here is an alternative:

```
YN = input("Create An Account Y/N:")
Y = "Yy"
login = "login"


if YN in Y:
    print ("Creating Account!")
    user = input("Enter A Username:")
    passwd = input("Enter a Password:")
    passwd2 = input("Verify Password:")
else:
    log = input("Would you like to login? If so type login.To close this application type q:")

if login in log:
    u = input("What is your username?")
    p = input("What is your password?")
else:
    print ("Ok Bye!")
    quit()


if YN in Y:
    while True:
    if passwd == passwd2:
        print ("Password Verified")
        file2write=open("Usernames.text",'w')
        file2write.write(user)
        file2write.close()

        file2write=open("Passwords.text",'w')
        file2write.write(passwd)
        file2write.close()
        break
    else:
        print ("Passwords Do not Match! One More Try")
        passwd = input("Enter a Password:")
        passwd2 = input("Verify Password:")  




f = open("guru99.txt", "r")
if f.mode == 'r':
    password =f.read()

print (password)
```

Comment: Noticed. Fixed.